# How to unzip a file in terminal and spit it out with specific file name?

Tags: command-line, files, unzip

I know I run `sudo unzip file.zip -d /path/to/dir`, but is there anyway to specify the output file name?

Comment: No, the file names will come from whatever is zipped...?

Comment: Have you already tried running unzip --help or man unzip?

Comment: Since (in general) zip archives can contain multiple files, it's not clear what *"the output file"* should mean

Comment: So, if I have a zipped xml file called "somezippedfile.xml.zip", and I would like to unzip it, and save the upzipped file in a directory called thisdirectory, with the new file name "unzippedfile.xml", how do I do that?  Or, is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 21):

If you are certain that your zip-archive contains only one file you can extract it to a different filename with

```
unzip -p > thenewFile
```

Explanation: `-p` tells `unzip` to extract the content directly to `stdout` which then gets redirected into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unzip7? Install it first (enter this in the terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

and then use this command in the terminal:

```
unzip (the zip file) -d (path to unzip)
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Are you certain that the command should be `unzip` instead of `unzip7`? As far as I know `-d` just gives the directory where to extract the file(s) to.

Comment: it is unzip for certain.